# Replace single quote at beginning of columns

Tags: awk, sed

I receive input files that are outside my control that contain a leading single quote in some columns, such as

```
'foo|'012|that's nice|bar
```

I want to remove all leading single quotes from each field, to get expected output:

```
foo|012|that's nice|bar
```

With awk, I assumed gsub regex metacharacters like `^` worked per-column, but it appears to only work at the beginning of a line:

```
$ echo "'foo|'012|that's nice|bar" | awk -F'|' '{gsub(/^'\''/,"")}1'
foo|'012|that's nice|bar
```

How can I remove leading single quote from each column?

Answer (score 5):

No need for `awk`, `sed` can do it with:

```bash
sed -E "s/(^|\|)'/\1/g"
```

The `-E` option to switch to extended regular expressions will be in the next version of the POSIX standard but is already supported by most `sed` implementations. Or you could use `perl` which supersedes both `sed` and `awk`:

```
perl -pe 's/(^|\|)'\''/$1/g'
```

Or:

```
perl -pe "s/(^|\|)\K'//g"
```

(`\K` to mark the start of what is `K`ept from the match).

Or:

```
perl -pe "s/(?<![^|])'//g"
```

(replaces `'` as long as it's not preceded by a character other than `|`).

Or with its `awk` mode:

```
perl -F'\|' -pe 's/^'\''// for @F; $_ = join "|", @F'
```

With `awk -F'|'`, you'd need to apply the substitution to every field, like in `perl`'s `awk` mode above:

```bash
awk -F'|' -v OFS='|' '
  {
    for (i = 1; i <= NF; i++) sub(/^'\''/, "", $ i)
    print
  }'
```

For `awk`, when the field separator is a single character, as a special case, it is not treated as a regular expression, so you don't need to escape that `|`.

`$` in `awk` is a unary operator that expects a number and returns the corresponding field if it's a number in between 1 and `NF`, the whole record if that number is 0 or empty strings¹ otherwise.

`sub()` and `gsub()` can take 2 or 3 arguments, if the third argument (the (one and only) subject of the substitution) is not supplied, then it defaults to the whole record (`$0`). `gsub()` differs from `sub()` the same way as `s/x/y/g` differs from `s/x/y/` in `sed`. `sub()` replaces only the first occurrence of the pattern, while `gsub()` replaces all of them.

Here the regex can match only once since it's anchored at the start, so `sub()` and `gsub()` won't make a difference.

IOW, `gsub()` is not about doing one substitution in each of the fields, it's about doing all the substitutions in *one* string, that string being the whole unsplit record by default.

---

<sup>¹ technically, they're treated as *numeric strings*. That is, they are treated as numbers if they look like a number and string otherwise. An empty string is treated as a string.</sup>

Comment: Maybe on the end of `for` the string should be `$i`, not `$ i`?

Comment: @RomeoNinov, `$` is an just another unary operator like `-` or `+`. You can use `$i`, `$ i`, `$ + i`, `$ ( i * 2 - i )`...

Comment: honestly i didn't know, thank you :)

Comment: Or `perl -pe 's/( ^ | [|] ) \x27/$1/gx'` to make up for some of the line-noise aspect of regexes and shell quoting.

Answer (score 2):

You would have to iterate over the fields and replace the quote character in each.  Stéphane shows how to do this using `awk` [in their answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/762829/116858).

```bash
$ mlr --csv --fs pipe -N put 'for (k,v in $*) { $[k] = sub(v, "^\047", "") }' file
foo|012|that's nice|bar
```

This uses [Miller (`mlr`)](https://miller.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) to read the input as a header-less CSV data set (with pipes as field delimiters).  For each record, the `put` expression iterates over all fields and removes the first character from them if it is a single quote (047 in octal).

---

Another approach with Miller which uses `apply()` to apply a function that deletes an initial single quote from a field.  The function is applied to each field in each record.

```bash
$ mlr --csv --fs pipe -N put '$* = apply($*, func(k,v) { return { k: sub(v, "^\047", "") } })' file
foo|012|that's nice|bar
```

Answer (score 2):

Using GNU awk for `gensub()` (also supported in some other awks but not required by POSIX yet):

```
$ awk '{$0=gensub(/(^|\|)\047/,"\\1","g")} 1' file
foo|012|that's nice|bar
```

I could have just done `print gensub(...)` above which would be a bit more efficient but I'm assigning to `$0` and printing with [`1`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24643330/1745001) for consistency with the other answers below and in case you actually need to do something with fields after the substitution.

Alternatively, using GNU awk for `RT`:

```
$ awk -v RS='|' '{ORS=RT; sub(/^\047/,"")} 1' file
foo|012|that's nice|bar
```

or using any awk:

```
$ awk '{gsub(/\|\047/,"|"); sub(/^\047/,"")} 1' file
foo|012|that's nice|bar
```

or also using any awk:

```
$ awk -F "[|]'" -v OFS='|' '{$1=$1; sub(/^\047/,"")} 1' file
foo|012|that's nice|bar
```

See http://awk.freeshell.org/PrintASingleQuote for why I'm using `\047` to represent `'`.

All of the awk [string-manipulation functions](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#String-Functions) (`*sub()`, `match()`, `*split()`, `index()`, `substr()`, `length()`, etc.), operate on whatever string you give them as an argument with, for those that don't require a string argument, the default being `$0` if no string is supplied as an argument. They don't separate the string into fields or anything else before operating on it so if you did want to change one field at a time for some reason then you'd need to write a loop to call `sub()` on each field one at a time:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="|"} {for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) sub(/^\047/,"",$i)} 1' file
foo|012|that's nice|bar
```

but that'd be less efficient than using either of these:

```
awk '{$0=gensub(/(^|\|)\047/,"\\1","g")} 1' file
awk '{gsub(/\|\047/,"|"); sub(/^\047/,"")} 1' file
```

since:

1. It's calling `*sub()` NF times per line instead of just 1 or 2 times.
2. It's referring to a field `$i` which forces awk to do field splitting while if you don't refer to a field in your script (as in the subsequent 2 scripts above) then most awks won't take the time to split each record into fields.
3. It's forcing awk to reconstruct `$0` from the fields every time a call to `sub()` changes a field, i.e. up to NF times per line.

Comment: Upvoted. Thanks for correcting. @EdMorton

Answer (score 0):

Using **Raku** (formerly known as Perl_6)

*Using `<(…)>` capture-markers:*

```
~$ raku -pe "s:g/  [ ^ | \| ]  <( \' )> //;"  file

#OR

~$ raku -pe 's:g/  [ ^ | \| ]  <( \c[APOSTROPHE] )> //;'  file
```

OR *using `<?after … >` positive Lookbehind:*

```
~$ raku -pe "s:g/  <?after ^ | \| >  \'  //;"  file

#OR

~$ raku -pe 's:g/  <?after ^ | \| >  \c[APOSTROPHE]  //;'  file
```

OR *using `<!after … >` negative Lookbehind with `<-[…]>` negative custom character-class¹:*

```
~$ raku -pe "s:g/  <!after  <-[|]> >  \'  //;"  file

#OR

~$ raku -pe 's:g/  <!after  <-[|]> >  \c[APOSTROPHE]  //;'  file
```

OR *using `split`/`join`:*

```
~$ raku -ne ".split(/ [ ^ | \| ] \'? /)[1..*].join('|').put"  file

#OR

~$ raku -ne '.split(/ [ ^ | \| ] \c[APOSTROPHE]? /)[1..*].join("|").put'  file
```

*Note the use of square bracket-grouping above where necessary (square brackets in Raku do not capture into `$0`, `$1`, etc.).*

---

Sample Input (testing empty column as well):

```
'foo|'012|that's nice|bar||baz
```

Sample Output (all examples):

```
foo|012|that's nice|bar||baz
```

---

<sup>¹ Thanks to @StéphaneChazelas for the Perl example.</sup>

https://docs.raku.org/language/regexes
https://raku.org